# Proving inequality in basic number theory

Tags: inequality

I'm trying to prove that if $x$ and $y$ are not both $0$ then $x^2+xy+y^2>0$

Considering the different cases of $x$ and $y$ I managed to prove the statement, but I'm stuck when considering the case $x\neq0$ and $y\neq0$. When both are not zero at the same time, $xy$ is either negative or positive. The statement follows easily from the positive case, but what about the negative?

Thanks.

Comment: Complete the square.

Comment: *Big* hint: What happens when you expand $(x+y)^2$?

Comment: @Afflon: It has nothing to do with Number Theory. The inequality holds for all real $x,y$ unless $x=y=0$.

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
(x+\frac{1}{2}y)^2+\frac{3}{4}y^2 \geq 0. 
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit, very clever way of writing the expression, it is now clear that it is greater than or equal to zero. Thanks!

Comment: @ReneSchipperus and TobyMak: Thanks for the answers, expanding/completing the square made it very easy to prove the statement, thanks!

Comment: @Afflon If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $t=\dfrac xy$. Then
$$x^2+xy+y^2=y^2(t^2+t+1)=y^2\biggl(\Bigl(t+\frac12\Bigr)^2+\frac34\biggr)\ge \frac{3y^2}4>0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that:

for $x,y$ with **equal sign**

$$x^2+xy+y^2= x^2-2xy+y^2+3xy=(x-y)^2+3xy>0$$

for $x,y$ with **opposite sign**

$$x^2+xy+y^2= x^2+2xy+y^2-xy=(x+y)^2-xy>0 \ \square$$