# Showing $x^2+xy+y^2>0$ and $x^4+x^3y+x^2y^2+xy^3+y^4>0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

In this exercise I have already done the part of demonstrating equality
$$x^n-y^n=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+\cdots+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})$$ but I don't know how to do the second part of the exercise in which I have to complete the following inequalities
$$x^2+xy+y^2>0 \qquad\text{and}\qquad x^4+x^3y+x^2y^2+xy^3+y^4>0$$

Can someone help me?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2549721 for the first one and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3516677 for the second one.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : For $x \ne y$, we have $ \frac{x^3 - y^3}{x- y} = x^2 +xy +y^2$, observe that $x-y$ and $x^3-y^3$ have same sign so  $\frac{x^3 - y^3}{x- y}$ will be positive.

Now similarly can you do the other one?